# Error when making backup in odoo 15 Database backup "Postgres subprocess ('pg_dump', '--no-owner', '--file=/tmp/tmpw2whn999/dump.sql', 'BBDD')"

Tags: postgresql, docker, odoo, odoo-14, odoo-15

I am using odoo 15 and migrated from the previous version.
When using the "Manage Databases" option and choosing a database it gives me the error
"Database backup error: Postgres subprocess ('/usr/bin/pg_dump', '--no-owner', '--file=/tmp/tmpw2whn999/dump.sql', 'BBDD') error 1"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUM9o.jpg)

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include a [mcve]?  It seems like you already have a resolution, if a temporary one using a debugging tool; do you still have a question?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I share my solution that helped me to solve the problem:
The problem was that when migrating from a previous version of Odoo, the Postgres client installer in the Docker container was not 15 and that's why it didn't let me make the backup.

Access docker container

1. docker exec -it -u root [ID CONTAINER] bash
2. sudo apt update
3. sudo apt install postgresql-client -y

I hope my answer will help you.